# Applescript to control terminal sessions

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I would like to control mac osx terminal via applescript as follows:

- when I press Command-N, I get a new terminal session for localhost (as usual)
- when I press Command-Shift-N, I open a new terminal session with a different background
  color, with an ssh session to a machine (with config specified in ~/.ssh/config)

How do I accomplish this using applescript ?

Answer (score 0):

My interaction with the Terminal is limited, but there is an `open` command that requires pointing to a file (untested code follows):

```
tell application "Terminal"
    open "/path/to/file"
end tell
```